# Remove last added character from edittext at any position

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I have one edittext, i want to set limit to it of 160 char. and if 161th char has typed by user then alert need to show. upto this everything working fine also i am deleting 161th char successfully . but it deletes only last char , if i enter 161th char inside paragraph i want to delete that one not last one.

```
  What i tried : 
  Edt_txt_keyIn.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use TextWatcher :

```
Edt_txt_keyIn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    private int position;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        position = start;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() > 160) {
            Edt_txt_keyIn.setText(s.delete(position, position + 1));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can try `android:maxLength="160"` if that suits your needs

Comment: maxlength is not a problem. (" if i enter 161th char inside paragraph i want to delete that one not last one.") this is my problem